# Assigning general classes as null in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, null

I am having kind of a trouble adapting a program from C# to C++. It's very commom given a class to assign it the null value. But C++ is not accepting the equivalent form 'nullptr'

```
class Point{
     public:
         int x,y;
}
//...
Point p = nullptr;
```

There is some way of solving it?

Comment: `p` is not a pointer in your example. Please use(refer to) a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: You'll need a pointer to do that: `Point* p = nullptr;` But you shouldn't really do that in c++. The memory management is completely different from c#.

Comment: Classes are value types in C++. You are trying to do C++ with a c# mindset, which will and can not work

Comment: "Adapting" alternate language code from one to another is a recipe for bad code. The most success you'll have comes from (a) know *both* languages *well*, (b) understand the *problem(s)* being solved by the former, and finally (c) properly implementing a solution to those problems in the latter. I suspect the root problem here is (a), as class-types are handle fundamentally differently in C# compared to C++.

Comment: If you intend to assign new objects to that pointer in the future, you must keep in mind that in C++ memory is unmanaged, you'll be the garbage collector, so to speak.

Comment: ... so better not to do that at all.  Instead, read one of the books in @Anoop's link and then start over.

Comment: You might be interested in [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: General C++ consens is to not create a `Point` until you are ready to initialize it. Having such "null" objects is a strong indicator that you are trying to declare the variable too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign `nullptr` to a class because a class is a type and not a variable. What you're doing by typing `Point p = nullptr;` is that you're asking the compiler to find a constructor of `Point` which accepts a `nullptr`.

You can either create an object of `Point` as an automatic variable by doing this:

```
Point p = Point{1, 2}; // sets x = 2 and y = 3
```

or simply like this:

```
Point p;
```

for which however you will need to define a constructor which initializes `x` and `y` because you haven't provided the member variables with default values.

Depending on the context in which this statement resides, `p` will either be allocated on the heap or on the stack. In case you're instantiating `p` in the main function, it will be the latter.

You can create a pointer to an object of `Point` by doing this:

```
Point* p = nullptr;
```

However, you will only have created a pointer. You will need to further take care of allocation, which you can do like this:

```
Point* p = new Point{1, 2};
```

in which case you should also free the allocated memory before your program ends like so:

```
delete p;
```

Comment: I ended doing the pointer for the class and modifying all the methods

Comment: @mateus that's the worst solution to do.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that `p` is a non-pointer type in your example. This means that it cannot be initialized with a `nullptr`. The type of `p` is `Point`.

You can make `p` a pointer to a `Point` so that you can initialize it with a `nullptr` as shown below:

```
Point *p = nullptr; //p is a pointer to non-const Point object
```

Or

If you want to create an object of the class type `Point` then one way of doing so is as follows:

```
Point p{1, 3};
```

I would also recommend referring to a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for a better understanding of the concept.

Comment: Yes, I was unsure because in c# it works, thank youuu